# What is a ratha, atiratha and maharatha?

Tags: mahabharata, war

I want to know what is the difference between ratha, maharatha and atiratha. I do not mean Maharathi, rathi, atirathi, etc.

Comment: The answer is already present.

Comment: Those words of that answer are different from those of my question, so there is no answer present there

Comment: These terms are used interchangeably..if these terms have different meanings, you should explain the Q little bit else it's unclear...

Comment: Rathi, Maharthi etc refer to different classes of warriors .. what do Ratha, Mahartha refer to? Do u hv any idea about that? @GabrielAlexanderGonzalezAgu

Comment: Ratha, Maharathi and Ratha, Maharatha are same. The terms first used are correct forms. Latter are distorted forms.